# Show lengthy content of a textview as a toast message android

Tags: android

I have a TextView and it contains lengthy contents. These textview are readonly and no scrolling provided. So that entire text cannot be seen in the textview. Now I want to show a toast message in the longClick event. But the toast message is shown in the bottom of the screen. How can I show it just below the selected TextView?

```
final Toast viewToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), packageId.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    packageId.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            viewToast.show();
            return false;
        }
    });`
```

Comment: toast are not for long message.. use dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the Toast at different location by using this method:

```
customToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

For custom location please go through this URL

[For custom position please go through this link](https://boltingupandroid.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/repositioning-toast-messages/)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show it just below the selected TextView?

To show Toast below of TextView or any View use `Toast.setGravity` method with X and Y offsets:

```
int coordinates[] = new int[2];
textView.getLocationInWindow(coordinates);
int xOffset=coordinates[0]+getWidth()/2;
int yOffset=coordinates[1]+ getHeight;
viewToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,xOffset,yOffset);
viewToast.show();
```

Change position of Toast on Activity Window using `xOffset` and `yOffset` according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try make your toast custom,

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF" />
```

Java code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layouts));

ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image1);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setText("Type your long message here");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```